# How to recreate the look of Android dialogs with other elements?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, dialog

I want to add an element to my app that looks nearly identical to the standard dialog created through an AlertDialog.Builder, but isn't one.
The important differences for me are:
 - my element must not block the UI behind it. 
 - my element shouldn't have any buttons

It would be used to display information somewhere without it affecting the users workflow, and without it being removable.

I've been trying to mimic the looks of the dialog using xml and layouts, but I've not succeeded on making them look perfect (or even close to perfect).

What kind of xml or code would be best to use?

Answer (score 0):

User dialogs. You can have buttons as part of the layout of the dialog and add click listeners to those. Please refer http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: This would be kind of the opposite what I'm attempting to do.
Your answer seems to give instructions how to make a dialog look like something else.
I'm trying to figure out a solution how to make something else, look like the standard dialog. (so it would look like a dialog, but wouldn't have the behavior)